# ESlint no-unused-vars

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, ecmascript-6, eslint

Здравствуйте.

Нужно заюзать [typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) в проекте, в котором используется [ESlint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars).

Самый простой пример кода:

```
// Can also be included with a regular script tag
import Typed from 'typed.js';

var options = {
  strings: ["<i>First</i> sentence.", "&amp; a second sentence."],
  typeSpeed: 40
}

var typed = new Typed(".element", options);
```

И всё работает как надо, за одним исключением:

ESlint кидает такуж ошибку:
  `27:9 error 'typed' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars`

По какой причине она возникает - понятно, однако, не понятно, как её красиво обойти.

Comment: Ну так а зачем вам эта переменная?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а зачем отвечать вопросом на вопрос ?
Я задал конкретный вопрос, если у вас есть решение, то я с радостью его приму, если нет, то для чего вы спрашиваете ? Чего вы хотите этим добиться ?

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает просто вызов конструктора без присваивания?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, new Typed ?

Comment: Вы бы лучше для начала рассказали, *зачем* вам надо её красиво обойти)

Comment: Ну, не красиво, это указать в .eslintrc.js, что нужно игнорировать ошибку от конкретного импорта. Боюсь, что благодаря такому способу, может накопится изрядное количество исключений в этом файле. 

А избежать для того, чтобы не ругалось :)

Comment: Вы так и не ответили зачем вам переменная которую вы не используете

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я дал ссылку на документацию type.js. Там описано именно такое использование. Вы можете увидеть, что в самих примерах, приведённых в документации, эта переменная ни разу не используется.

Если же я использую просто new Typed(...), то линтер ругается на другую ошибку. Я и спрашиваю, как сделать грамотно так, чтобы линтер не ругался ,и чтобы линтер не игнорировал эту ошибку.

Comment: На какую другую?

Answer (score 1):

*Обойти* предупреждение можно просто использовав данную переменную, например, передав ее в какую-нибудь функцию:

```
var typed = new Typed(".element", options);
console.log(typed);
```

Кроме этого можно отключить конкретные правила или полностью проверку для данной строки с помощью специальных комментариев

```
var typed = new Typed(".element", options); // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

Либо

```
// eslint-disable-next-line    
var typed = new Typed(".element", options);
```

**[Demo](https://eslint.org/demo/#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)**

Comment: Использовал вариант с console.log(typed); но не считал его правильным, по этому и задал вопрос.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik, поэтому он и называется _обход_. Но этот способ может быть не применим, если будет использоваться какое-нибудь правильно запрещающее консоль